# Huge Binary File Gets Shrinked by almost 100%?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, binaryfiles, binary-data

I created a binary file with 4,000,000 'double' values (a total of 32MB).
Then, I zipped it, and to my surprise the file shrunk to 46KB only.

That's almost a 100% shriking! is it for real? or am I missing something here?

Comment: What are the values?  All zeros?

Comment: double values between -1000 - 1000.

Comment: There used to be a program called `lzip`, that could compress files up to 0% of their original size. the site seems to have died since, but you can find and archived copy here: http://web.archive.org/web/20021213025323/http://lzip.sourceforge.net/index.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compression rate depends on the algorithm **and** the data. E.g., 32MB worth of zeroes compress pretty well.

## Update

My computer science basics are pretty rusty but I can speculate from what I remember. A double can use let's say 8 bytes (64 bits). A range between -1000 and 1000 are like 2^11 consecutive integers. So it's to expect that 64-11 = 53 bits are possibly shared by all the numbers and most of the compressed space will be used for the remaining 11 bits. That's a saving of 53/64 = 82.2% already.

Now, data is probably not completely random. Any decent compressor should be able to detect repeated strings and obtain a further gain. An over simplified example:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbb ==> 30a10b
```